# User and DB schema conflict

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-schema

I want to have a user and a DB schema with the same name. Executing the below script

```
CREATE DATABASE db1
GO
EXECUTE sp_addlogin @loginame = 'abc',
                    @passwd   = '123456789',
                    @defdb    = 'db1'
GO
USE db1
GO
EXECUTE sp_grantdbaccess @loginame   = 'abc', 
                         @name_in_db = 'abc'
GO
CREATE SCHEMA abc
GO
```

gives me the error:

> Msg 2714: There is already an object named ‘abc’ in the database.

Is there any way to handle this without using different names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend against sp_ procedures for this, and I wouldn't make the database their default until after you've added them as a user in that database.

```
CREATE DATABASE db1;
GO
CREATE LOGIN abc WITH PASSWORD = '123456789';
GO
USE db1;
GO
CREATE USER abc FROM LOGIN abc;
GO
ALTER LOGIN abc WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE = db1;
GO
CREATE SCHEMA abc;
GO

-- if you want them to own the schema:
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON schema::abc TO abc;

-- if you just want abc to be their default schema:
ALTER USER abc WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = abc;
GO
```